# Send ID but show label

Tags: jquery, ajax, tag-it

I am using the jQuery plugin [Tag-It](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) for handling auto-suggestion and tagging. I am getting the data using an `Ajax` call which is working fine.

The data at the moment is being returned in the following format:

```
{"itemID":"ItemName"}
```

For example:

```
{"1":"Yellow","2":"Green"}
```

This is going fine.

What I want to do is have the user click on the returned tag, and have the data stored in the hidden field something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tag['itemID']['itemName']"/>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do it, has anyone any experience with this and able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: When you say that the data is returned by Ajax, do you mean that you are using the autocomplete feature to get the list of tags available to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this requires passing the extra data that is returned from the autocomplete Ajax call to the Tag-it tag events.

Add a variable `itemId` to a scope, which will be used to store the additional data from the autocomplete item:

```
{
    var itemId;
```

Get a reference to the tags element so that the create tag behavior can be called

```
    var theTags = $('#tags');

    theTags.tagit({
```

Handle the `select` event of the autocomplete and store the additional data from the selected autocomplete item, then create the tag.

```
        autocomplete: {
            source: [{id:1,value:'New 1'},{id:2,value:'New 2'}],
            select: function(event,ui) {
                itemId = ui.item.id;
                theTags.tagit("createTag", ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        },
```

Handle the `afterTagAdded` event for Tag-it. In here any custom behavior to modify the just added tag can be implemented.

```
        afterTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
            if (itemId) {
                $(ui.tag).find('input')
                     .attr('name', "tag[\'" + itemId+ "']['" + ui.tagLabel + "']");
                itemId = null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

See a working example of this solution at http://jsfiddle.net/DCJsj/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the tips. Managed to get this working now.